# JS While to Ensure number can't be divided again

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, while-loop, do-while

I had a problem, in which the JavaScript coding JS did not bring the results that I want.

I want results like this:

```
Hasil 10, Sisa 0
Hasil 5 Sisa 0
Hasil 2 Sisa 1
Hasil 1 Sisa 0
```

Where the incidence of the above, I want to divide 20 by 2 to ensure figure 20 can not be divided again.

But when I made it with JS, JS not even produce anything. This is my code:

```
function bagihbs( numbers, bagin ) {
    var res = "";
    var idx = 0;
    while ( idx < parseInt(numbers / bagin) ) {
        var bagi = parseInt(numbers / bagin);
        var sisa = numbers % bagin;

        res += "Hasil = "+bagi+", Sisa = "+sisa;

        return bagihbs(bagi, bagin);

        break;
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(bagihbs(20, 2));
```

Please help me and give examples :D . There is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/nttacghf/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the current and then return, since res changes every inner scope of each iteration of your recursion. Also res is not global

Added `res` => `return res + bagihbs(bagi, bagin);`

Check snippet

```js
function bagihbs( numbers, bagin ) {
    var res = "";
    var idx = 0;
    while ( idx < parseInt(numbers / bagin) ) {
        var bagi = parseInt(numbers / bagin);
        var sisa = numbers % bagin;

        res += "Hasil = "+bagi+", Sisa = "+sisa + "\n";

        return res + bagihbs(bagi, bagin);

        break;
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(bagihbs(20, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't clarify in your question what you want to happen in the case where the number you are dividing by is larger than the beginning number, so here are two possibilities.

This solution will result in your expected output and will output a blank string if the number isn't divisible by the given number.

```
function bagihbs( numbers, bagin ) {
    var bagi = parseInt(numbers / bagin),
        sisa = numbers % bagin;

    if(bagi > 0) {
        return "Hasil = " + bagi + ", Sisa = " + sisa +
               "\n" + bagihbs(bagi, bagin);
    }

    return '';
}
console.log(bagihbs(20, 2));
```

This solution will output a 0 and the remainder for the final division.

```
function bagihbs( numbers, bagin ) {
    var bagi = parseInt(numbers / bagin),
        sisa = numbers % bagin,
        res = "Hasil = " + bagi + ", Sisa = " + sisa;

    if(bagi > 0) {
        return res + '\n' + bagihbs(bagi, bagin);
    }

    return res;
}
console.log(bagihbs(20, 2));
```

The biggest difference between the two is where you calculate the return string. If you want the remainder posted it is calculated before checking if there is another division to do. If you don't want the remainder posted, it is created only if you know there is another division to do. I also removed your loop because it was unnecessary since you were calling the function recursively and the loop was essentially functioning as an if statement.